# Passing at once all columns of a data frame as arguments for a function (R)

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm really surprised in regards to how difficult it is to come across documentation for my particular necessity. I find lots of documentation pertaining to how a given function can be called several times, each time taking as input a different column of a data frame —and therefore mutating **each** column by applying to **each** one the very same function—. That is not what I require.

Instead, I want to call a given function only once, and pass to it all the columns of a data frame as arguments. That is, using as input **all** the variables in the data frame, I want to create a new variable.

For instance, let *df* be the following data frame:

| V1 | V2 | V3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-07-15 UTC--2020-07-15 UTC | 2020-09-17 UTC--2022-09-17 UTC | 2018-07-19 UTC--2018-09-19 UTC |
| 2019-07-15 UTC--2020-07-15 UTC | 2020-09-17 UTC--2022-09-17 UTC | 2018-07-20 UTC--2019-07-20 UTC |

Notice that all three variables are intervals created through the lubridate package.

Now, I want to create a new column which displays the intersection of the intervals.

```
df = df %>% mutate(new_variable = lubridate::intersect(V1, V2, V3))
```

Since *df* has only a few columns, and neither of them has a complicated nor long name, it is not too much of a hassle to have to write explicitly the name of each variable. But writing the column names would no longer be a smart move if rather than having 3 columns my data frame had, say, 10 columns. Actually, programmers are known to be lazy and I'm no exception: I don't want to have to write down the column names, even if I'm dealing with a single-column data frame.

### Edit

This is possibly related to the issue at hand. Let *x* be the following vector of intervals:

```
[1] 2019-07-15 UTC--2020-07-15 UTC 2017-11-22 UTC--2017-11-22 UTC
[3] 2020-09-17 UTC--2022-09-17 UTC 2018-07-19 UTC--2018-09-19 UTC
[5] 2018-07-20 UTC--2019-07-20 UTC 2018-07-20 UTC--2019-07-20 UTC
```

Now, I will try to use do.call in order to pass each element of *x* as an argument for the function intersect.

```
> do.call(lubridate::intersect, list(x))

Error in int_standardize(y) : 
  el argumento "y" está ausente, sin valor por omisión
```

The error message translates to `argument "y" is absent, with no default value`.

Comment: Reshape to a long format, then use a function inside `purrr::reduce` or base `Reduce`?

Comment: please include a sample of your data using `dput(head(df))`

Answer (score 1):

You were close when your thought about `do.call()`.

Your example contains no intersection so I added one row that intersects. I also added a `id` row:

```r
df = structure(list(id = 1:3, V1 = new("Interval", .Data = c(31622400, 31622400, 34300800), start = structure(c(1563148800, 1563148800, 1563148800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), tzone = "UTC"), V2 = new("Interval", .Data = c(63072000, 63072000, 65750400), start = structure(c(1600300800, 1600300800, 1594944000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), tzone = "UTC"), V3 = new("Interval", .Data = c(5356800, 31536000, 34214400), start = structure(c(1531958400, 1532044800, 1532044800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate(id=row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(var=do.call(intersect, as.list(value)))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#    id  var                           
# <int>  <Interval>                    
#     1  NA--NA                        
#     2  NA--NA                        
#     3  2020-07-17 UTC--2020-08-15 UTC
```